# Game Input for Single Actions

Tags: java, events

So I'm not 100% sure what you would call this type of keypress, but it is essentially a `keyTyped` event but in reverse order. Instead of being triggered when the button is released, it is triggered when the button is first pressed, but can't be triggered again until the button is released and pressed again.

Right now I have events for `buttonDown` and `buttonUp` and I also have two `HashMap`s to keep track of the `currentInput` and `previousInput` of each action in the game (jumping, moving, crouching, etc...) How can I provide a function that when called returns true for this type of button push?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there : you need to detect whether the key has *just* been pressed. So it is currently down, but wasn't an instant ago, which is easy to test since you have both states.

```
bool pressed(Action action) {
    return !previousInput[action] && currentInput[action];
}
```

Comment: That's what I have currently, the problem is that the `previousInput` doesn't update until the button is then released. In other words, as long as you keep the button held down, this method will continue to return true because the previous and current state of the input aren't being updated.

Comment: @FaTalCubez I see. But then your `previousInput` is useless as-is : it can only contain the opposite of `currentInput`, since you only update it when there's a toggle. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: I've been able to get it so that you have to lift up the key and press it again before repeating the action. However, my program still breaks when it comes to the case where you jump, mid-jump you release the key and press it again, and then when you land (still holding down the key), it jumps again.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing the following:

1. Create an integer variable.
2. Set it to zero if the current state is `up`.
3. Increment it if the current state is `down`.
4. Only activate the desired method when the value is zero and the state is down. Alternatively, if you increment prior to checking, only activate if and when the value is 1. Good luck!

Comment: I ended up just putting in an `update()` call that sets the `previousInput` to whatever value is in the `currentInput`. The update is called once a frame after checking for input. I then test to see if `currentInput` is true and `previousInput` is false.